# Vue 3 & Vite built or preview shows blank page with no error log

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vite

I'm asking for help. I use vuejs 3 + vite + TypeScript to make my frontend application. Everithing is fine when I start development server with `npm run dev` but when I try to build it (`npm run build` and then serve it) or preview it (`npm run preview`) I'm only able to display a blank page without any error in my browser javascript console.

#### Some precisions

- Everytime I try to access to my application root route (`/`) and to another public route (`/login`)
- When I build it, I use `npm run build` then I move to dist `cd dist` then I serve it with serve (command `serve`)
- I've no inusual logs in `npm run preview` nor in `npm run build` then `serve` console

#### Versions

- VITE v3.2.7
- Vue v3.2.41
- Node v18.17.1
- NPM v9.6.7
- Serve v14.2.1

#### Further diagnostic

I achieved to run Chrome Vue Devtools in both development mode & production mode using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781351/vue-js-is-detected-on-this-page-devtools-inspection-is-not-available-because-it/75825663#75825663). Seems that my `<RouterView>` appears Components under `<Root>` in developement mode but not in production (or preview) mode :

*Vue Devtools in developement mode :*
[image: Vue Devtools developement mode]

*Vue Devtools in preview or production mode :*
[image: Vue Devtools in preview or production mod]

Note that every other resources accessible by Chrome Vue Devtools seems to be identical in both cases : Routes, I18N Ressources, Vuex.
Also note that page title and icon loads properly even if the page stay blank.

#### Relevant Project Files

```
//vite.config.ts

// Plugins
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueI18n from '@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'


// Utilities
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { resolve, dirname } from 'node:path'

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => ({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueI18n({
      include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './src/locales/**'),
    }),
    VueI18nPlugin({ /* options */ }),
  ],
  define: { 
    'process.env': {},
    __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: mode !== 'production' },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.jsx',
      '.mjs',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx',
      '.vue',
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    host: true,
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    exclude: [
      '**/node_modules/**'
    ]
  }
}))
```

```js
//package.json

  "name": "my-frontend-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build --mode development", // "--mode development" has been added for devtools as said above, the bug happend before I added it.
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint . --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "test": "vitest",
    "coverage": "vitest run --coverage"
  },
[...]
```

```
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-BE" class="h-full">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/tenants/compagny/favicon-180x180.png" sizes="180x180" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/tenants/compagny/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/tenants/compagny/favicon-48x48.png" sizes="48x48" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/tenants/compagny/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/tenants/compagny/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>compagny - Home</title>
</head>

<body class="h-full">
  <div id="app" class="h-full"></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
//src/main.ts

// Components
import App from './App.vue'
import MasonryWall from '@yeger/vue-masonry-wall'
import VueTailwindDatepicker from "vue-tailwind-datepicker"
import store from '@/core/store'
import './index.css'
import { i18n } from '@/locales/i18n.configuration'


// Composables
import { createApp } from 'vue'

// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'

export { i18n };

const app = createApp({
  extends: App
})

registerPlugins(app)

app.use(i18n)
app.use(MasonryWall)
app.use(VueTailwindDatepicker)
app.use(store)
app.mount('#app')
```

```
//src/plugins/index.ts

/**
 * plugins/index.ts
 *
 * Automatically included in `./src/main.ts`
 */

// Plugins
import { loadFonts } from './webfontloader'
import router from '@/router'

// Types
import type { App } from 'vue'

export function registerPlugins (app: App) {
  loadFonts()
  app
  .use(router)
}
```

```js
//src/App.vue

<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  //
</script>
```

```
//src/router/index.ts

// Composables
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import LocalAuthenticationService from "@/core/services/auth/LocalAuthentication.service";

// Routes
import coreRoutes from '@/core/router'


const routes = [
  ...coreRoutes,
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    if (LocalAuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
      // User is authenticated, proceed to the route
      next();
    } else {
      // User is not authenticated, redirect to login
      next({ name: "login" });
    }
  } else {
    // Non-protected route, allow access
    next();
  }
});

export default router
```

```
//src/core/router.ts

const BasicLayout = () => import("./views/layouts/BasicLayout.vue");
const ViewBasicLogin = () => import("./views/auth/BasicLogin.vue");
const TemporaryHome = () => import("./views/temporary/TemporaryHome.vue");

export default [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: BasicLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        name: "home",
        component: TemporaryHome,

      }
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: ViewBasicLogin,

  }
]

[...]
```

*If you need to see other files or log output to diagnose please ask me.*

#### Things I've already tried (and that do not work)

- Add `base: './'` or `base: '/'` into `vite.config.ts` / `defineConfig` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72005195/3243992))
- Add to my router a route that catch all the request to redirect to home ([source](https://passe-de-mode.uedasoft.com/tips/software/frontend/vue/vue01.html#issue)) using `path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*'` with vue3 syntax.

Comment: You register everything in main.ts except vue-router. Coincidentally it's the only plugin not working.  Maybe `registerPlugins` function needs to be looked at.  Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Hi @yoduh . Thanks for the remark. I forgot to show my `src/plugins/index.ts` in my original post and I've just edited it so you can now see how vue-router is called into `regiterPlugins`. Regards.

Comment: Did you notice the error in the browser console?